# Как правильно хранить большие JSON в БД?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, хранение-данных

Периодически обращаюсь к различным API (типа яндекса) и тяну оттуда информацию, затем записываю в БД. PostgreSQL в моем случае. Ответ от API получаю в JSON и весь JSON заливаю в ячейку соответствующей таблицы. Но все время думаю над тем, а нормальное ли это решение. Мне в целом удобно получать массив и обрабатывать его целиком, а не разбивать на столбцы и потом брать из базы. Но встает вопрос, а если JSON который я записываю будет мягко скажем большим. Например информация о продажах за год, средненького ретейла, в таком случае моя практика не окажется хлипким решением?

Comment: Если вы в самом sql не работаете отдельно с элементами этого json, а читаете всегда его целиком и в дальнейшем не модифицируете, то вполне нормально его хранить одним полем. Особенно если у вас нет точной структуры. Конечно надо понимать, что в таком виде он занимает больше места на диске, так как названия полей в нем дублируются в каждой записи

Comment: Вы не заметили, что в postgrese имеется тип данных json? По такому json даже запросы можно составлять. (Хотя может у Вас postgres старенький) Кроме того никто не запрещает рядом с собственно json хранить какую-нибудь ключевую информацию, предварительно извлечённую из этого json. Либо в полях той же таблицы с json-полем, либо в связанных с ней таблицах.

Comment: @Sergey Да заметил, и пользуюсь этим в крайних случаях. но как показала практика вытягивание всего json объекта на клиента и обработка на нем производительнее, чем вытягивание отдельных полей в самом запросе (даже на jsonb). Поэтому я на больших данных не могу рекомендовать активную работу с json на стороне БД

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Понял, что не совсем ерунду сделал. За тип данных отдельное.

Answer (score 2):

В PostgreSQL есть два типа данных - JSON (по сути обычное текстовое поле, хранящее строковое представление JSON) и JSONB (бинарное представление данных). Оба типа выполняют полный контроль валидности переданного значения.

JSONB обеспечивает более эффективную обработку и должен использоваться, если над этим значением будут выполняться какие-то операции на сервере (поиск, обновление и пр.). Кроме того, JSONB несколько компактнее. Но следует учитывать, что JSONB полностью формализует значение, и при его запрашивании восстанавливает его. Соответственно это может приводить к изменению сохраняемого значения (только для объектов). Основные изменения, с которыми можно столкнуться:

1. при сохранении объекта, в котором присутствуют несколько одноимённых свойств, будет сохранено только одно из значений, то, которое самое последнее по тексту, все остальные будут утрачены
2. при восстановлении объекта его свойства будут отсортированы в лексикографическом порядке

Если же задача только хранить и отдавать как есть, без обработки - то JSON предпочтительнее. И соответственно если значение содержит одноимённые атрибуты или порядок атрибутов в объекте имеет какое-то значение, следует однозначно использовать JSON.

Comment: Я изучал вопрос компактности хранения json, записывая одинаковые данные в json и в jsonb и потом находя в файле данных записи и сравнивая размеры. На тех данных которые мне надо было хранить оказалось, что если исходный json текст избавлен от форматирования то он в БД занимал на 5-30% (в зависимости от данных) меньше места, чем загруженный в jsonb. Мне не удалось найти ситуаций при которых jsonb бы выигрывал по размеру. Да, возможно мои данные довольно специфичны, значения в основном числовые, но после этого эксперимента утверждать что jsonb несколько компактнее я бы не стал

Comment: @Mike Да, избавление от форматирования изрядно пакует значение, и в этом случае действительно JSON получается компактнее. Ибо даже в JSONB все значения по-прежнему хранятся в строках (во всяком случае, выдавить ошибку преобразования/переполнения мне не удалось).